# Bloomberg BDS Formula Function to VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, bloomberg

Below is the Bloomberg BDS formula im using to pull Data Set information from Bloomberg. This formula usually works by manual plugin into a spread sheet but its too troublesome to do it manually for about 80 CUSIPs IDs.

```
=BDS(A5&"" CUSIP"",""MTG_Cash_Flow"",""MTG_Face_AMT"",C5,TEXT(""Settle_DT"",""mmddyyyy""),$B$1,""Headers=y"",""cols=6;rows=184"")"
```

My goal is to covert the above formula and setup as an Excel VBA formula to pull the information monthly by a click of a button to generate the information.

Since i am unfamiliar with Bloomberg formula format setup in VBA. I would like to get some help with my formula below that I've tried setting up. I've gotten multiple errors when running the formula below but cant figure it out.
I've also attached the image of the worksheet I'm working on as well for an example.

[Spreadsheet Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8WNy.png)

[Revised BDS Formula 3.14.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKfgi.png)

[Date Field Used 3.14.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDkCG.png)

[Error Message 3.14.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBi91.png)

```
Sub CalcValues()

Dim cusipID As String
cusipID = Sheets("Input").Cells(5, 1)

Dim Cusip As String
Cusip = "CUSIP"

Dim MTGFLOW As String
MTGFLOW = "MTG_CASH_FLOW"

Dim MTGAmt As Long
MTGAmt = Sheets("Input").Cells(5, 3).Value

Dim SettleDT As String
SettleDT = "Settle_DT"

Dim dtStart As String
dtStart = Formart(SettleDT,Format(Sheets("Input").Range("B3"), "MMDDYYYY"))

Sheets("CFs").Cells(2, 1) = "=BDS("" & CusipID & "","" & CUSIP & "","" & MTGFLOW & "","" & MTGAmt & "","" & SettleDT & "","" & dtStart & "")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `"=BDS(" & CusipID & "& "" CUSIP""," & MTGFLOW & ", ""MTG_Face_AMT""," & MTGFace & "," & EndDate & ",""Headers = y"",""cols=6;rows=184"")"`
for the formula (not sure I got it totally right Bloomberg-wise)

TIP: `""` is translated as a quotation mark in the cell itself, while `"` is telling VBA that a string is starting/ending

Also, you can't do `Dim CusipID as Integer` given that the cell you refer to contains letters as well (38378KH93) - just `Dim CusipID as String` right away.
`MTGFace`, on the other hand, is a number (face value), so that can be saved as `Long` or `Double` (mind, not `Integer`).

Comment: I have implemented your recommendations. I only have 1 error left which is the date labeled as "dtStart". The error message say its an "#N/A Invalid Parameter: & dtStart &". Do you happen to know how to adjust it to read yyyymmdd format or to get it to work? I just cant seem to get that part to work at all :(